# How Grafana handle time series with million points?

Tags: grafana

the company I work has a system capable of generating a lot of information, and they want to visualize that data using Grafana.

An example of information load: in 24h it's probable that we've easily generated over 10 million points.

In this case, how does Grafana handle this amount of data? Will it be handled automatically or shall we need to implement some back-end plugin to skip cursor and get a few points in order to render graphs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling of the raw data points is usually left to the storage backend (Eg. Graphite, OpenTSDB, Prometheus...). Grafana then will query the backend asking it to downsample that data to an specific resolution (eg. 1 point per minute) using the adequate operation (avg, min, max...).

In the end, things work like this:

1. You have a collector sampling a metric every second and sending to the backend
2. Grafana will ask for that metric on a specific time window (eg. last day) and with an specific resolution (1 point per minute) using AVG as aggregation function.
3. The backend will aggregate all available data on that window to the resolution asked and return to Grafana.
4. Grafana draw that to the user.
5. Now, **if/when** the user see something interesting on the period between 10am and 12am, it will zoom out there, and Grafana will ask more granular data (eg. every 5 seconds).

This way, it can keep the data size in a manageable size for the end-user.

As a reference, see the API for OpenTSDB: http://opentsdb.net/docs/3x/build/html/user_guide/querynodes/downsample.html

Comment: Thank you Vitor!! Are you available to work as freelancer?

Comment: can you provide a link to grafana docs where you can choose the aggregation function (i.e. in your post you said `avg, min, max`)? i tried to find a link to the grafana docs but i could not find a link. (your link is for a specific datasource `opentsdb` but the question is about grafana. for instance i am using datasource prometheus.).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Each Grafana data source use a different syntax, specific to the backend. For Prometheus, look at https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus. What Grafana itself provides, is a bunch of variables that help you in selecting the proper downsample/resolution. See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__interval